# Emulator Images in android studio and real device images do not match

Tags: java, android, opencv, desktop-application

i'm developing an app to manipulate image taken by camera in real time. Though when i run the same code in android studio emulator i get the colors i need. Though when i do it in real device the colors are shifted.

for example Dark blue in emulator is slightly lighter. Red in emulator is lighter in real device. i tried it in several real devices. In all cases colors are lighter than expected.

Why this is happening?? Is there any differences in webcam in a laptop which emulator pickup the image and real device cameras??

How can i make the colors same as the images in webcam pictures in emulator?

Comment: As long as all the mobiles give the same color then most likely your pc camera has something wrong with contrast or u need to stabilize the colors on PC (Just assuming)

Comment: But the pc's webcam give the wanted output.. Is there a way to change the contrast as you suggest in the opencv javacameraview? Or in imwrite () method in Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer for my issue. Just needed to adjust the contrast of my laptop's webcam. All working as expected.